# Is there another method to call form like drupal_get_form?

Tags: views, theming, hooks

I try to get two form in one page from drupal 6 module to drupal 7 module but when i run its just show text "Array". is there any method same like drupal_get_form for calling another form at one page ?

[image]

Here my code

```
$output = '';
$output = drupal_get_form("filter_cash",$awal,$akhir,$jprog);
$output .= dafcash($awal,$akhir,$jprog);
return $output;
```

Hook_menu :

```
function cash_menu() {
    $items['cash'] = array(
        'title' => 'Pengajuan Cash',
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
        'page callback' => 'cash_pglistgl',
        'access arguments' => array('cash-new'),
        );
    $items['cash/daftar'] = array(
        'title' => 'Daftar-cash',
        'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
        'page callback' => 'cash_pglistgl',
        'access arguments' => array('cash-new'),
        );
    $items['cash/init/2'] = array(
        'title' => 'Tambah cash',
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
        'page callback' => 'page_cash_init',
        'access arguments' => array('cash-new'),
        );
    $items['cash/add'] = array(
        'title' => 'cash-tambah',
        'callback arguments' => array('without_'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'page callback' => 'page_cash_add',
        'access arguments' => array('cash-new'),
        );
    $items['cash/editinit'] = array(
        'title' => 'EDIT cash',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'page callback' => 'page_cashinitedit',
        'access arguments' => array('cash-new'),
        'file' => '',
        );
    $items['cash/editadd'] = array(
        'title' => 'EDIT cash',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'page callback' => 'page_cash_addedit',
        'access arguments' => array('cash-new'),
        'file' => 'cash.edit.inc',
        );
    $items['cash/editdelete'] = array(
        'title' => 'EDIT cash',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'page callback' => 'page_cash_deledit',
        'access arguments' => array('cash-new'),
        'file' => 'cash.edit.inc',
        );
    $items['cash/batal'] = array(
        'title' => 'cash-batal',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'page callback' => 'page_cash_batal',
        'access arguments' => array('cash-new'),
        );
    $items['cash/delete'] = array(
        'title' => 'cash-hapus',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'page callback' => 'page_acsh_del',
        'access arguments' => array('petty-new'),
        );
    $items['cash/delete_list'] = array(
        'title' => 'cash-hapus',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'page callback' => 'page_cash_del_list',
        'access arguments' => array('cash-new'),
        );
    $items['cash/edit'] = array(
        'title' => 'cash-ubah',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'page callback' => 'page_cash_edit',
        'access arguments' => array('cash-new'),
        'file' => 'cash.edit.inc',
        );
    $items['cash/view_detedit'] = array(
        'title' => 'cash-Edit detail',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'page callback' => 'page_cash_view_edit',
        'access arguments' => array('cash-new'),
        'file' => 'cash.edit.inc',
        );
    $items['cash/view_detadd'] = array(
        'title' => 'cash-tambah detail',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'page callback' => 'page_cash_view_detadd',
        'access arguments' => array('cash-new'),
        );
    $items['view_detdel'] = array(
        'title' => 'cash-hapus',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'page callback' => 'page_cash_view_detdel',
        'access arguments' => array('cash-new'),
        );
    $items['cash/view'] = array(
        'title' => 'cash-lihat detail',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'page callback' => 'page_cash_view',
        'access arguments' => array('cash-new'),
        'file' => 'cash.view.inc',
        );
    $items['cash/editdetail'] = array(
        'title' => 'Detail cash - Ubah',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'page callback' => 'page_cash_editdetail',
        'access arguments' => array('cash-new'),
        'file' => 'cash.edit.inc',
        );
    $items['cash/editalldata'] = array(
        'title' => 'cash-ubah',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'page callback' => 'page_cash_editalldata',
        'access arguments' => array('cash-new'),
        'file' => 'cash.edit.inc',
        );
    $items['cash/editall'] = array(
        'title' => 'cash-ubah',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'page callback' => 'page_cash_editall',
        'access arguments' => array('cash-new'),
        'file' => 'cash.edit.inc',
        );
    $items['cash/editall2'] = array(
        'title' => 'cash-ubah',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'page callback' => 'page_cash_editall2',
        'access arguments' => array('cash-new'),
        'file' => 'cash.edit.inc',
        );
    $items['cash/view_edit'] = array(
        'title' => 'cash-lihat edit',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'page  callback' => 'page_cash_view_edit',
        'access arguments' => array('cash-new'),
        'file' => 'cash.edit.inc',
        );
    $items['cash/pdf'] = array(
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'page callback' => 'page_cash_pdf',
        'access arguments' => array('cash-new'),
        );
    $items['cash/xls'] = array(
        'type' =>MENU_CALLBACK,
        'page callback' => 'page_cash_xls',
        'access arguments' => array('cash-new'),
        );
    $items['autocomplete'] = array(
        'title' => 'autocomplete',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'page callback' => 'find_noreff_auto',
        'access arguments' => array('cash-new'),
        );
    return $items;
}
```

Comment: drupal_get_form returns a renderable form array. Does dafcash return a renderable array as well?

Comment: Also, can you add your hook_menu code?

Comment: sure I've added the code above

Comment: print drupal_render(node_add('form_name'));
Check this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should render it through drupal_render() method to get desired result.

```
$output = '';
$output = drupal_render(drupal_get_form("filter_cash",$awal,$akhir,$jprog));
$output .= dafcash($awal,$akhir,$jprog);
return $output;
```

Comment: I've use drupal_render but still doesn't work.

Comment: drupal_render definitely does work. What is the other function doing?

Comment: Check if drupal_get_form is returning an array with all form fields...